# Javascript : print globalobject through already defined function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print the global object window through this Print object without using the variable `window`.

```
Print = function(){
    this.print = function() {
    console.log(this);
    } 
}
var print = new Print();
```

I found the way to call the window with :

```
var globalObject = (function(){return this;})();
```

Now, how can I print this `globalObject` with the variable 'printer'?

EDIT : I have to use the defined print function. I cannot modify the print object.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are printing `this` in the `print` method, you need a way to change the `this` used in that function.

One way is by using [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) which passes the first argument as `this` to the function.

```js
var globalObject = (function(){return this;})();

Print = function(){
    this.print = function() {
    console.log(this);
    } 
}

var print = new Print();

print.print.call(globalObject);

// It takes a while to the snippet to print `window` properties in the console
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Make edit to your code as follows:

```
Print = function(globalObject){
    this.print = function() {
    console.log(globalObject);
    } 
}
var print = new Print(globalObject);

print.print() // Prints window object
```

Comment: Would it be possible to imagine a solution without modifying the print object ? That was my real question. I have to use the defined print function. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I do not understand. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: globalObject is probably undefined

Answer (score 0):

This modular pattern will help you,

```
var globalObj = (function(w){

  return {
    printWindowObj: function(){
      console.log(w);
    }
  }

})(window);


globalObj.printWindowObj();
```

Comment: Would it be possible to imagine a solution without modifying the print object ? That was my real question. I have to use the defined print function. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: means you dont want to use global window.print function

Answer (score 0):

Your `print` function logs the `this` object. Normally, that's the object that contains it - in this case, `Print`.

If you want to print your `globalObject`, and refer to it as `this` in `print`, you have to bind it manually.

Something like this would work:

```
Print = function(globalObject){
    this.print = function() {
        console.log(this);
    }.bind(globalObject);
}
var print = new Print(globalObject);
print.print(); // globalObject
```

What this is doing is creating `Print` with a reference to your `globalObject`, and then binding it to the `print` function.

You can play around with it [here.](http://jsbin.com/cucizoyotu/edit?js,console)

Comment: OP said that they "have to use the defined print function"

Answer (score 0):

Just omit the new:

```
 Print();
 print();
```